# Does using the in operator affect the use of indexes?

Tags: mysql, index, execution-plan

Does using the `in` operator affect the use of indexes? For example, is it possible for `WHERE id IN (10)` to cause the optimizer to ignore an index?

Specifically, I'm trying to understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45989185/4458445) from StackOverflow. The question asks why an index is not being utilized (in MySQL), and the answer suggests that it could be due to the use of `in` with only one value. Eg `WHERE id IN (10)` might get the index ignored, while `WHERE id=10` would be fine.

I've briefly looked around on Google, and skimmed through some MySQL docs, but I can't find any reference to `in` affecting the optimizer's decision to use an index. Neither with a single value, nor multiple values.

Assuming that the `IN` values are the same datatype as the column they are comparing, can they affect the index usage?

The question that I linked to was for MySQL, but I work in other DBs, so I'd be interested in knowing if this is a universal thing to note about indexes, or if it's a quirk with MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that happens in MySQL then it's a quirk to MySQL.  Since you asked about other databases as well I decided to test it out on my postgres database.  On a table with a little over 70 million rows it produces exactly the same explain for the following two queries (with the index):

```
explain select * from myschema.my_list where my_column in (232);
explain select * from myschema.my_list where my_column = 232;
```

which is:

```
'Bitmap Heap Scan on my_list  (cost=68093.11..4109456.90 rows=1656844 width=994)'
'  Recheck Cond: (my_column = 232)'
'  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_list_2  (cost=0.00..67678.90 rows=1656844 width=0)'
'        Index Cond: (my_column = 232)'
```

It doesn't diverge until I add in multiple elements in the list:

```
 explain select * from myschema.my_list where my_column in (232,79);
 explain select * from myschema.my_list where my_column = 232 or my_column = 79;
```

which is (respectively):

```
'Bitmap Heap Scan on my_list  (cost=172208.28..7050980.15 rows=4290987 width=994)'
'  Recheck Cond: (my_column = ANY ('{232,79}'::integer[]))'
'  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_list_2  (cost=0.00..171135.53 rows=4290987 width=0)'
'        Index Cond: (my_column = ANY ('{232,79}'::integer[]))'

'Bitmap Heap Scan on my_list  (cost=177390.73..7066890.07 rows=4230402 width=994)'
'  Recheck Cond: ((my_column = 232) OR (my_column = 79))'
'  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=177390.73..177390.73 rows=4290987 width=0)'
'        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_list_2  (cost=0.00..67678.90 rows=1656844 width=0)'
'              Index Cond: (my_column = 232)'
'        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_list_2  (cost=0.00..107596.63 rows=2634142 width=0)'
'              Index Cond: (my_column = 79)'
```

I would take his answer with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks for your time Indiri. I tested the same thing in Sybase ASE, and didn't encounter any query plan differences either. I'll wait a few days before accepting your answer, in case anybody else comes along with a fringe use case.

Answer (score 2):

`IN` with a single item turns into `=` as one of the Optimizer's first "steps".

Your referenced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989068/why-isnt-mysql-using-the-index-on-our-table ("this answer") is *not* about failing to use an index for `IN`; it is more complex than that.

And your question is more complex than you realize.

There are many reasons for the Optimizer to not use an index for `IN`.  But the emphasis should be on **not use an index** not on **for IN**.

If you have a particular example we can discuss it.

**Furthermore**

From the Operator_trace, you can probably see "steps" including 
 something like *"expanded_query": "/* select#1 */ select 
`tbl`.`col2` AS `col2` from `tbl` where (`tbl`.`col1` = 123456)"* as the "expansion" of *... where col1 IN(123456)*.

Comment: My comment asking for clarification got deleted, and I'm not sure why. You put thought into your answer, so I want to explain that my question is not about the query in the question I linked to. I simply linked to the claim in the answer, to provide context as to why I would ask this question. Based on you saying _"the emphasis should be on __not use an index__ not on __for IN__"_, I take it that `IN` on its own does not affect the choice of index, and that any optimization problem would be the same for both `id IN (10, 20)` as `id=10 or id=20`? In other words, an answer of "no" to my Q?

Comment: `WHERE id IN (10)` and `WHERE id IN (10,20)` go down different paths in the Optimizer.  The first is equivalent to `id=10` which opens up a lot of good optimization doors.  The second (same as `(id=10 OR id=20)`) is quite messy to optimize.  The Accepted Answer spells out how some non-MySQL engine operates differently; it is less obvious with MySQL's `EXPLAIN`.